# Gps Tracking using polyline marker

Tags: android

I want to build a app where user can track location using GPS i am adding marker on map and using polyline connecting that markers i want to track whether that person is out of that  polyline boundry how to do that . Please help me thanks

Comment: what do you already have? is the problem drawing a map or the math to find out if a point is inside a poligon or ....? if you are note more specific it is likely that your question is closed as beeing to broad

Comment: I want to find out point is inside or outside polygon